# TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern in Python Script

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using a script that I found on the internet to seperate an excel spreadsheet into individual spreadsheets based on the Unique Value  in the spreadsheet.

My code is as follows:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd  # pip install pandas
import os

# Define & create output directory
output_dir = Path(__file__).parent / "output"
output_dir.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)


# Define Excel file path
excel_file = Path(__file__).parent / "partnercontacts2.xlsx"

df = pd.read_excel(excel_file)
column_name = "Company"
df[column_name] = df[column_name].str.strip().str.title()
unique_values = df[column_name].unique()

for unique_value in unique_values:
    df_output = df[df[column_name].str.fullmatch(unique_value).fillna(False)]
    output_path = output_dir / f"{unique_value}.xlsx"
    df_output.to_excel(output_path, sheet_name=unique_value[:31], index=False)
```

After a few thousand seperations, I'm getting this error

> "TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern"

Any idea what I can do to fix this?

Comment: Can you provide the entire Python exception stack? This will show exactly which line raised the `TypeError`.  Also, can you print a count of the lines processed? This will help you determine exactly which line in the input file causes the error. It may have missing or malformed data.

Comment: I ended up fixing it. Turns out it was a floating integer error. I fixed it with this code ``` for unique_value in unique_values:
    unique_value = str(unique_value)```